# How to associate only one public key with a restricted shell like scponly?

Tags: ssh, account-restrictions, authorization

I'd like to use a passwordless key to perform e.g. unison synchronization while being able to SSH into the server only with a password-protected key. The usual way of using `scponly` is changig the login-shell of my server account, but that is too global. Can an entry in `authorized_keys` achieve this instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `command` keyword in authorized_keys to restrict execution to one single command for particular key, like this:

```
command="/usr/local/bin/mysync" ...sync public key...
```

Update:
If you specify a simple script as the command you may verify the command user originally supplied:

```
#!/bin/sh 

case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in 
/path/to/unison *) 
$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND 
;; 
*) 
echo "Rejected" 
;; 
esac
```

Comment: Doesn't that simply execute that command? I'd like sshd to only allow a `ssh server -c unison ...` while any other attempt to connect with that key should _not_ execute anything but simple refuse connecting

Comment: It is possible, I updated the answer. But what the reason for such behavior? If you have the key you have permission to sync. So you rather connect and do the job or don't connect at all...

Comment: Perfect, I used `case "$(basename $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND)" in \n unison *)` though. The reason is I want to have a private key that doesn't require a password so unison can run unattended (e.g. as a cronjob), while that key should not be capable of allowing a SSH access. Of course unison could be abused to replace `authorized_keys`...